# Android check file error "Type mismatch: inferred type is Context but Path! was expected"

Tags: java, android, json, file, kotlin

I am trying to introduce local JSON storage into an app that I am making.  I have used this method of JSON storage before, but I have never gotten these errors; `Type mismatch: inferred type is Context but Path! was expected` and `Type mismatch: inferred type is String but LinkOption! was expected`
The errors appear as follows on context and JSON_FILE:

```
 constructor (context: Context) {
        this.context = context
        if (exists(context, JSON_FILE)) {
            deserialize()
        }
    }
```

Here is the class:

```
package ie.wit.models

import com.google.gson.Gson
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken
import org.jetbrains.anko.AnkoLogger
import java.nio.file.Files.exists
import kotlin.random.Random
import ie.wit.helpers.**/
import android.content.Context
import com.google.gson.Gson
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken
import org.jetbrains.anko.AnkoLogger
import ie.wit.helpers.*
import java.nio.file.Files.exists
import java.util.*


val JSON_FILE = "bookings.json"
val gsonBuilder = GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create()
val listType = object: TypeToken<ArrayList<ValetModel>>(){}.type

fun generateRandomId(): Long {
    return Random().nextLong()
}

class ValetJSONStore: ValetStore, AnkoLogger{
    val context: Context
    var bookings = mutableListOf<ValetModel>()

    constructor (context: Context) {
        this.context = context
        if (exists(context, JSON_FILE)) {
            deserialize()
        }
    }

    override fun findAll(): List<ValetModel> {
        return bookings
    }


    override fun create(valet: ValetModel) {
        valet.id = generateRandomId()
        bookings.add(valet)
        serialize()
    }

    override fun update(valet: ValetModel) {
        val bookingsList = findAll() as ArrayList<ValetModel>
        var foundBooking: ValetModel? = bookingsList.find{p -> p.id == valet.id}
        if(foundBooking != null){
            foundBooking.brand = valet.brand
            foundBooking.model = valet.model
            foundBooking.numberPlate = valet.numberPlate
            foundBooking.date = valet.date
        }
        serialize()
    }

    override fun delete(valet: ValetModel) {
        bookings.remove(valet)
        serialize()
    }

    private fun serialize(){
        val jsonString = gsonBuilder.toJson(bookings, listType)
        write(context, JSON_FILE, jsonString)
    }

    private fun deserialize() {
        val jsonString = read(context, JSON_FILE)
        bookings = Gson().fromJson(jsonString, listType)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To explain why you are getting that error:** If you check the documentation for `exists(..)` for `import java.nio.file.Files.exists`it expects a `Path`and not a `Context`:

> ```
> /**
>      * Tests whether a file exists.
>      *
>      * <p> The {@code options} parameter may be used to indicate how symbolic links
>      * are handled for the case that the file is a symbolic link. By default,
>      * symbolic links are followed. If the option {@link LinkOption#NOFOLLOW_LINKS
>      * NOFOLLOW_LINKS} is present then symbolic links are not followed.
>      *
>      * <p> Note that the result of this method is immediately outdated. If this
>      * method indicates the file exists then there is no guarantee that a
>      * subsequence access will succeed. Care should be taken when using this
>      * method in security sensitive applications.
>      *
>      * @param   path
>      *          the path to the file to test
>      * @param   options
>      *          options indicating how symbolic links are handled
>      * .
>      * @return  {@code true} if the file exists; {@code false} if the file does
>      *          not exist or its existence cannot be determined.
>      *
>      * @throws  SecurityException
>      *          In the case of the default provider, the {@link
>      *          SecurityManager#checkRead(String)} is invoked to check
>      *          read access to the file.
>      *
>      * @see #notExists
>  */
> public static boolean exists(Path path, LinkOption... options) {
>     try {
>         if (followLinks(options)) {
>             provider(path).checkAccess(path);
>         } else {
>             // attempt to read attributes without following links
>             readAttributes(path, BasicFileAttributes.class,
>                            LinkOption.NOFOLLOW_LINKS);
>         }
>         // file exists
>         return true;
>     } catch (IOException x) {
>         // does not exist or unable to determine if file exists
>         return false;
>     }
>
> }
> ```

Probably in other classes where you have implemented the same thing maybe you are trying to use an `exists(..)` method imported from somewhere else different from `java.nio.file.Files.exists`?

**To check if that file exists or not you have many options, but for now I can list you two options, of which one you already tried to use (exists(..) which is available from API 26):**

```
package com.example.myapplication

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import java.io.File
import java.nio.file.Files.exists
import java.nio.file.Paths


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val JSON_FILE = "bookings.json"

        // One option to check if file exists (available from API 26)
        if (exists(Paths.get(JSON_FILE))) {
            //
        }

        // Another option to check if file exists (available from API 1)
        val file = File(JSON_FILE)
        if (file.exists()) {
            //
        }
    }
}
```